# Intergrating Paypal into my shopping cart

Tags: php, session, paypal, checkout

I have developed my own shopping cart and now I want to integrate Paypal once the user click the checkout button.

I need to pass the item details over to Paypal based on what the customer has added to the cart. I believe my code below does this however the checkout button does nothing when clicked on. Tried everything but for some reason the form doesn't even see the checkout button!

```
<?php
$checkout = "<form action='https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr' method='post'>";
$checkout .= "<input type='hidden' name='cmd' value='_cart'><input type='hidden' name='upload' value='1'>";
$checkout .= "<input type='hidden' name='business' value='craig@biosboss.com'>";

$count = 1;
$checkout .= "<input type='hidden' name='item_name_" + $count + "' value='" + $item['name']+ "'>";
$checkout .= "<input type='hidden' name='item_number_" + $count + "' value='" + $count + "'>";
$checkout .= "<input type='hidden' name='quantity_" + $count + "' value='" + $item['qty'] + "'>";
$checkout .= "<input type='hidden' name='amount_" + $count + "' value='" + $item['price'] + "'>";
$count = $count + 1;
?>

<input type='hidden' name='currency_code' value='GBP'>
<input type='hidden' name='lc' value='GB'>
<input type='hidden' name='return' value='http://www.biosboss.com/checkout?confirm=Confirm&confirmTerms=on'>
<input type='hidden' name='cancel_return' value='http://www.biosboss.com/checkout'>
<input type='hidden' name='notify_url' value='http://www.biosboss.com/checkout?confirm=Confirm&confirmTerms=on'>
<input class='securePaymentButton' type='submit' value='here'>
<?php $checkout .= "</form>"; ?>
```

Comment: the form has no action, where do you think its posting to?

Comment: Sorry my code has been updated added the wrong code!

Comment: looks like there are form inputs outside the form tags. where is $checkout actully echoed?

Comment: Put the actual end result here instead of the dynamic code generating it.  The end result is all that matters.  We can see what's wrong there, and then you can figure out how to adjust your dynamic code based on that.